# How to store username and password in one application and retrieve values in another application nativescript angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I just want to save user name and password in one nativescript application. Then in Second nativescript application, I have to retrieve the saved username and password.

I don't know how to achieve this in nativescript angular2. Any help is appreciated.thanks.

Comment: Is this data to be stored on the device? If so a possible way is to use a local db (e.g. SQLite, Crouch, etc) and set up the database in an external storage location(android) and/or the equivalent for ios so any app could potentially access the DB. This however may not be secure enough for your needs

Answer (score 2):

Try using LDAP server to store username and password .

Access these information in Webserver using any of server side languages using LDAP protocol .

Expose this functionality using known protocol like HTTP. Then Angular can access user information using any  REST Api call .

Answer (score -1):

I know one way for passing secure data between application which might be helpful for now.

You can store the encrypted username and password in the local storage of the browser and than retrieve these encrypted username and password from local storage for further processing.

For encryption, you can use RSA-128 with timestamp.

Comment: Local storage is per domain, nativescript apps are native applications, why would they have to go to an arbitrary website to access their local storage?